# AcquireTokenAsync not found for auth context when trying to get token

Tags: c#, powershell, authentication, oauth, token

I am trying to get the bearer token to call an API via a powershell script like so:

```
function GetAuthToken
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $ApiEndpointUri,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $AADTenant
)
$adal = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\" + `
            "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
$adalforms = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\" + `
                "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal) | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms) | Out-Null

$clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"
$redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
$authorityUri = “https://login.windows.net/$aadTenant”

$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authorityUri



$authResult = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ApiEndpointUri, $clientId,$redirectUri, "Auto")
$authResult.Wait();

return $authResult
$ApiEndpointUri = "https://management.azure.com/" #change this to graph api uri
$AADTenant = 'GUID' #AAD tenant guid
$token = GetAuthToken -ApiEndPointUri $ApiEndpointUri -AADTenant $AADTenant
$header = @{
'Content-Type'='application\json'
'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
}

$request = ``
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Headers $header -Method Get).value
```

However, acquiretokenasync is failing with this error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "AcquireTokenAsync" and the argument count: "4".
```

Any ideas why I am getting this issue? AcquireTokenAsync takes 4 arguments from what I know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a AcquireTokenAsync overload with 4 parameters.  You also need to make sure you are casting your parameters correctly.

Take a look at the overload list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync.aspx).  Which of these overloads do you think you're using?  You'll notice that all of your parameters are strings yet none of the overloads accept only strings.

Comment: Hmm, I used this in a c# method and it worked fine:
Task<AuthenticationResult> resultTask = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                (AuthServerAddress,
                clientId,
                new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"),
                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false));

Comment: Is it because I'm using a version 3+ of the ActiveDirectory dll? Any idea how I would translate the above to one of the acquiretokenasyncs listed in the overload list?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on Windows 10 build 1703 (though the script was working on build 1607).  I had version 3.13.9 installed of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.  I replaced those assemblies with [version 3.13.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/3.13.8)  and restarted PowerShell, which cleared my error.